# Need to read a value in a XDocument based on the value of an attribute

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

I have an xml document that looks like this:

```
<RESPONSES>
    <RESPONSE STATUS="OK">
        <ALBUM>
           <URL TYPE="COVERART" SIZE="THUMBNAIL">http://akamai-b.cdn.cddbp.net/cds/2.0/cover/60AA/2DF9/B94B/72C8_thumbnail_front.jpg</URL>
           <URL TYPE="ARTIST_BIOGRAPHY">http://web.content.cddbp.net/cds/2.0?id=6F64C8E01EA6253B&amp;client=10395648&amp;class=biography&amp;type=text/plain&amp;tag=02sq63myXqi8O9GLtyVrTB2Q0HTdtZEIU0LuGDlIoDRvQGTE2lkKnsdQ</URL>
        </ALBUM>
    </RESPONSE>
<RESPONSES>
```

I need to get the value of the COVERART URL and the ARTIST_BIOGRAPHY URL, so I need to get the value of the element URL where the attribute TYPE="COVERART" and the value of the element URL where the attribute TYPE="ARTIST_BIOGRAPHY" and I can't figure out how to do this (although I'm sure it's a simple answer ;-)

I've tried both:

```
   var albums = new List<Album>();
        try
        {
            albums = (from item in inputDoc.Descendants("ALBUM") 
                select new Album
               {
                   Biography = (string)item.Element("URL").Attribute("TYPE"),
```

and

```
                   CoverArt = (string)item.Element("URL").Attribute("COVERART")
               }).ToList();
```

and neither gives me what I'm looking for. Can someone please help me!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the element which has an attribute called type, with a value of "coverart" or "artist_biography". You need a Predicate for this:

```
List<Album> albums = xDoc
    .Root
    .Descendants("ALBUM")
    .Select(e =>
        new Album()
        {
            CoverArt = e
                .Elements("URL")
                .First(u => u.Attribute("TYPE").Value == "COVERART")
                .Value
                .ToString(),
            ArtistBio = e
                .Elements("URL")
                .First(u => u.Attribute("TYPE").Value == "ARTIST_BIOGRAPHY")
                .Value
                .ToString()
        }
    ).ToList();
```

Note I normally will have the inner statement on one line but expanded here on SO for readability.

Comment: Thanks David. This works for the coverart, but for the bio I get {"Sequence contains no matching element"} System.Exception {System.InvalidOperationException} and I know that there is in fact a bio in the result set.

Comment: I tested this with the small xml snippet you provided and it worked for me. Can you double check you posted the correct xml?

Comment: Thanks David - the problem was on my end - it was the xml that I was feeding the web service that was flawed. Thanks for your help on this.